# Sharepoint survey automate email when response submitted

Tags: designer-workflow, email, survey

I created a sharepoint survey and I am trying to automate an email every time a response is submitted. I made a workflow in sharepoint designer but it is not sending an email. How do I get it to work? I checked for errors, saved, and published it and I used my email and I am the owner of the survey.

Comment: Could you provide the logic/steps you used for the workflow? It's difficult to determine what the error is without knowing what's been done.

Comment: I have just the send email step and then finish. Do you know if it is possible to get email notifications when a survey response is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another step. If "Modified By" is not blank then email These Users.

When submitted the Created By and Modified Fields will be Updated and should trigger the email. Make sure you have the workflow to trigger on item creation.

[image]

Comment: so would I add modified by first?

Comment: Yes, if you try using

If Current Item:Modified By is not empty
Send email to (Selected user).

Make sure that the workflow will run on item creation. I'm not 100% sure this will work but the logic here is that the modified field will be updated when an item is created and the workflow will use this change to trigger itself and send the email.

Comment: are you using sharepoint designer 2013?

Comment: I have it so that when item is created it starts.

Comment: Stage:Stage 1
 If Current Item: Modified By equals not empty
  Email Engstrom, Hanna
Transition to stage
 Go to End of Workflow
This is what I made it look like and it still does not work. I am wondering if sharepoint survey does not allow workflows

Comment: I'm using SP2013 and created my workflow in SPD2013